# Put the children of my table at the same height with flexbox if the content of one is longer than the content of the other

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am creating a comparison table with flexbox and I have the problem that when creating the content in the lists, not being the same size does not focus the headers such as pros and cons or the same title if it has a sentence or two.

The truth is that I have tried a lot and I have no idea, I leave the code I have so far, I have left it as minimized as possible because I already had a lot of cocoa.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/pruebas.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section id="comparative" class="primary comparative">
      <h2></h2>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column mv">
          <p class="badge">Más vendido</p>
            <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="/" alt="" /></a>
            <p class="product-title">Producto</p>
            <div class="enl-comp">
              <a class="button" href="#" target="_blank">VER OFERTA EN AMAZON</a>
              <a class="opinion" href="#" target="_blank">Lee opiniones</a>
            </div>
            <p class="pros">Pros</p>
            <ul>
              <li>Más autonomía</li>
            </ul>
            <p class="cons">Contras</p>
            <ul>
              <li>Vaciado de la caja</li>
            </ul>
            <a class="button" href="#" target="_blank">VER OFERTA EN AMAZON</a>
        </div>
        <div class="column mv-1">
          <p class="badge">Más valorado</p>
            <!-- PRODUCTO 2 -->
            <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="/" alt="" /></a>
            <p class="product-title">Producto</p>
            <a class="button" href="#" target="_blank">VER OFERTA EN AMAZON</a>
            <a class="opinion" href="#" target="_blank">Lee opiniones</a>
            <p class="pros">Pros</p>
            <ul>
              <li>Más autonomía</li>
              <li>Más autonomía</li>
              <li>Más autonomía</li>
            </ul>
            <p class="cons">Contras</p>
            <ul>
              <li>Vaciado de la caja</li>
            </ul>
            <a class="button" href="#" target="_blank">VER OFERTA EN AMAZON</a>
          </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Y el css:

```
.row{
    display: flex;
}
.column{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex: 0 0 20%;
}
.inside-col{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: stretch;
}
.opiniones{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: stretch;
    align-items: stretch;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Flex will only make the immediate children same height. And in your code, it is properly making both `column` same height. But since you need the children of the `column` to be of same height, we need to re-structure the html such that each column has only one section.

```css
.row{
    display: flex;
}
.column{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex: 0 0 20%;
    /* temp css*/
    padding: 0 15px 15px;
    border: 1px solid;
}

.inside-col{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: stretch;
}
.opiniones{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: stretch;
    align-items: stretch;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/pruebas.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section id="comparative" class="primary comparative">
      <h2></h2>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column mv">
          <p class="badge">Más vendido</p>
          <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="/" alt="" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="column mv-1">
          <p class="badge">Más valorado</p>
          <!-- PRODUCTO 2 -->
          <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="/" alt="" /></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column mv">
            <p class="product-title">Producto</p>
            <div class="enl-comp">
              <a class="button" href="#" target="_blank">VER OFERTA EN AMAZON</a>
              <a class="opinion" href="#" target="_blank">Lee opiniones</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column mv-1">
            <p class="product-title">Producto</p>
            <a class="button" href="#" target="_blank">VER OFERTA EN AMAZON</a>
            <a class="opinion" href="#" target="_blank">Lee opiniones</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column mv">
            <p class="pros">Pros</p>
            <ul>
              <li>Más autonomía</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="column mv-1">
            <p class="pros">Pros</p>
            <ul>
              <li>Más autonomía</li>
              <li>Más autonomía</li>
              <li>Más autonomía</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column mv">
            <p class="cons">Contras</p>
            <ul>
              <li>Vaciado de la caja</li>
            </ul>
            <a class="button" href="#" target="_blank">VER OFERTA EN AMAZON</a>
        </div>
        <div class="column mv-1">
            <p class="cons">Contras</p>
            <ul>
              <li>Vaciado de la caja</li>
            </ul>
            <a class="button" href="#" target="_blank">VER OFERTA EN AMAZON</a>
          </div>
        </div>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wouldn't there be a way to fix it with the structure I was suggesting, it seems crazy to me when it comes to filling it out and making it responsive.